# Как сделать переход по ссылке в value при клике на кнопку?

Tags: html

```html
<form method="POST" action="/account/pay/">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="template-category" class="form-control">
<option value="online">Через пополнение</option>
<option disabled value="of">Через офис</option>
<option disabled value="of">Через партнёра</option>
</select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="template-category">Способ пополнения</label>
    <select id="template-category" name="type" class="form-control">
<option value="1" href="/account/pay/">Через карту</option>  
<option value="2" href="/account/pay/">Через Яндекс Деньги</option>
<option value="http://site.ru/accout/payeer/" action="/accout/payeer/">Через Payeer (Qiwi)</option>
<option disabled value="4">Через WebMoney</option>
<option disabled value="4">Через PayPal</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <p>
    <button type="submit" style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="reviewButton" onclick="location.href=$('select').val();"> Продолжить</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Как сделать переход по ссылке в value при клике на кнопку?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#reviewButton").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = $('select[name=type] option:selected').val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#!">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="template-category" class="form-control">
        <option value="online">Через пополнение</option>
        <option disabled value="of">Через офис</option>
        <option disabled value="of">Через партнёра</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="template-category">Способ пополнения</label>
      <select id="template-category" name="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="/account/pay/">Через карту</option>     
        <option value="/account/pay/">Через Яндекс Деньги</option>
        <option value="http://www.qiwi.kz/">Через Payeer (Qiwi)</option>
        <option disabled value="4">Через WebMoney</option>
        <option disabled value="4">Через PayPal</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br>
    <p>
      <button type="submit" style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="reviewButton"> Продолжить</button>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Верхний код куда вставлять?

Comment: @Egor в файл script.js или в HTML  на той же странице вот так: <script> тут код </script>  Не забудьте подключить jquery.